# How many different ways to pay $2018, using only quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies?

Tags: combinations, integer-partitions

I have seen solutions that show how this is done for amounts such as $1. Namely I consulted this webpage's explanation--

https://www.maa.org/frank-morgans-math-chat-293-ways-to-make-change-for-a-dollar

--which I found helpful in understanding the general method. However, I am unsure of how to scale this up for an amount so large.

Comment: It would be useful to have the numerical value for each coin.

Answer (score 0):

It's the coefficient of
$x^{2018}$
in
$\dfrac1{(1-x)(1-x^5)(1-x^{10})(1-x^{25})}
$.

Stick that in your symbolic algebra systen
and see what you get.

Alternatively,
Wolfy says that this is
$\dfrac1{\left(x^{41} - x^{40} - x^{36} + x^{35} - x^{31} + x^{30} + x^{26} - x^{25} - x^{16} + x^{15} + x^{11} - x^{10} + x^6 - x^5 - x + 1\right)}
$
which would allow you to
setup a recurrence
(of order 41)
to generate the successive coefficients.